# Image Upload to PDF on Webpage

Tags: php, pdf, html, jscript

im new in Webdevelopment and I wanted to ask you ("THE EXPERTS") if you could guide me or give some hints how to do following Webpage:

I want to upload 3-5 Images, place them automatically horizontally on a PDF and let the user download the PDF. I don't want to store the images so after you reload the page the images should be gone.

Could you help me how to realize such webpage? Or atleast which way I should use? Jscript, html5, php etc...

Best regards
Machete

Comment: Here is a suggestion from "an expert". Please show us some code as to what you have tried and where you are stuck. We're not gonna realize a webpage for you here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i just wanted to ask the experts what would be a good point to start this webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a pdf-libary like [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/%20FPDF).
Especially take a look at the `Image()` function ([Documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm)).

Comment: Thanks i will look for it! Helped me a lot allready!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. :) If an answer seems to be right for you, please upvote and accept it. thanks!

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you Roman, i just accepted it because my ranks is to low to upvote :/

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty, create a php script that executes something like this on the shell:

```
convert image1.png image2.png image3.png output.pdf
```

you need to have imagemagick installed.
There are more elegant ways to do that.